# Creating set of tasks with email reminder

Tags: web-apps, project-management, notification, workflow, reminders

I am looking for a web app that has the following feature: I have a template for a workflow (task) that consists of smaller subtasks that need to be done one after another.

The due dates for the subtasks always are the same (+1 week), but the content of each subtask is different, so I can't just use recurring tasks.

Let's say the workflow is for a sales cycle. The template would then look like this:

> - WORKFLOW-TEMPLATE: Lead
>
>   - SUBTASK1: Initial contact with Lead (due date: today + 7d)
>   - SUBTASK2: Send Mail to Lead (due date: duedate SUBTASK1 + 7d OR today + 14d)
>   - SUBTASK3: Call lead (due date: date SUBTASK2 + 7d OR today + 21d)

For every lead that I get, I would then use the workflow template, rename it to the customers name and have dynamic tasks based on creation date for this specific lead.

Before due date the user should be notified by mail about the task.

[Asana](https://asana.com/) has a tutorial on task sets, but this does not create dynamic due dates and just preserves the subtasks.

Do you know of any web app/service/open source library that support such sets of tasks?

Comment: With "app" you mean a) an Android app, b) iOS app, c) web-app, or d) any application? Might be helpful to [edit] your question, pointing out which OS should be supported ;)

Comment: A web app is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is there is software that can do this: the [CEITON](http://ceiton.com/CMS/EN/workflow/ctws-system.html#PPS_Components) workflow system allows tree-like structure for hierarchy of tasks, supports templates and dynamic due dates, and it's web-based.

The bad news is that it's not open-source or particularly cheap.

As disclosure, I work for the parent company of the company that makes the software.

Comment: Do you use this software? Could you elaborate a bit more about how it does the things the OP needs? Maybe add a screenshot or two?